# Porque los contadores no aumentan¿?

Tags: javascript, contador

No encuentro ningun fallo en la sintaxis y a la hora de ejecutarlo no me marca ningun error, pero ni tanto como "numLetra" ni "error" aumentan en las iteraciones del while.

```js
function receptarLetra(palabra){
    teclas = document.addEventListener("keydown",function(event){
        var teclaPresionada = event.key;
        var numLetra = 0
        var error = 0
        while(numLetra < palabra.length || error == 5){
            if(teclaPresionada == palabra[numLetra]){
                alert("tecla presionada: "+ teclaPresionada)
                dibujarLetraCorrecta(teclaPresionada)
                ++numLetra 
                console.log("el numero de letra es: "+numLetra)
                break;
            }else{
                dibujarLetraIncorrecta()
                dibujarHorca(error)
                ++numLetra 
                ++error 
                console.log("el numero de letra es: "+numLetra)
                console.log("el numero de error es: "+error)
                
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    )
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías agregar todo lo que se imprime en la consola?

Comment: Ahi presione algunas teclas y eso es lo que muestra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

El problema es que cada vez que ejecutas la función `receptarLetra` inicializas las variables `numLetra` y `error`, estas deberían existir afuera de tu función para que al ejecutarse puedan incrementar.

Ejemplo (Tuve que comentar algunas cosas porque el código que pusiste en la pregunta no incluía esas funciones):

```js
var numLetra = 0;
var error = 0;
function receptarLetra(palabra){
    teclas = document.addEventListener("keydown",function(event){
        var teclaPresionada = event.key;
        
        while(numLetra < palabra.length || error == 5){
            if(teclaPresionada == palabra[numLetra]){
                alert("tecla presionada: "+ teclaPresionada);
                //dibujarLetraCorrecta(teclaPresionada);
                ++numLetra;
                console.log("el numero de letra es: "+numLetra);
                break;
            }else{
                //dibujarLetraIncorrecta();
                //dibujarHorca(error);
                ++numLetra;
                ++error;
                console.log("el numero de letra es: "+numLetra);
                console.log("el numero de error es: "+error);
                
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    )
}
receptarLetra('prueba');
```

Answer (score 0):

Te falta agregar los `;` a las líneas

```
function receptarLetra(palabra){
    teclas = document.addEventListener("keydown",function(event){
        var teclaPresionada = event.key;
        var numLetra = 0;
        var error = 0;
        while(numLetra < palabra.length || error == 5){
            if(teclaPresionada == palabra[numLetra]){
                alert("tecla presionada: "+ teclaPresionada);
                dibujarLetraCorrecta(teclaPresionada);
                ++numLetra;
                console.log("el numero de letra es: "+numLetra);
                break;
            }else{
                dibujarLetraIncorrecta();
                dibujarHorca(error);
                ++numLetra;
                ++error;
                console.log("el numero de letra es: "+numLetra);
                console.log("el numero de error es: "+error);
                
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    )
}
```

Comment: Ahi lo acabo de cambiar y siguen sin incrementarse